# How to change to a new AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am new to AWS Amplify and I need to change to a new user pool since the default settings are not sufficient. I see there is a way to create a new user pool and then migrate users from the old pool to the new pool ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-change-user-pool-attributes/)), but I would prefer to just change the default pool to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change standard user pool attributes after a user pool is created. Instead, create a new user pool with the attributes that you want to require for user registration.

You have 2 options to migrate your users to the new User Pool:

1. You can migrate users when they sign-in using Amazon Cognito for the first time with a user migration Lambda trigger. With this approach, users can continue using their existing passwords and will not have to reset them after the migration to your user pool. [Lambda Migration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html)
2. You can export users and import them to a new user pool with a CSV file, but your users will have to change their password.[Import - Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still in the dev phase so I'm not worried about migrating users. I am stuck with "connecting" my new user pool to the existing app so that when a new user will register, they will register with the new user pool and not the old one. And the same goes for signing in, where I want the user to sign in with the new user pool and not the old one

Comment: As far as I understand you want to reconfigure your userpool. Have a look at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource might answer your question `userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',`